# Create folders in $HOME from txt file

Tags: bash

I have a file structure like
folder/subfolder1/folders.txt,docker-compose.yml
folder/subfolder2/folders.txt,docker-compose.yml

These text files contain folders to be created in my $HOME, like appdata/subfolder1,subfolder2

I’m trying to create a script that does the following;
It should go over all the files in folder/* and watch for .txt files in subfolders. If there is no text file in subfolder1 I want it to echo “no txt file in subfolder1” but if there is a txt file in subfolder1 it should read it line by line and create the folders in my $HOME. It should also do the same for subfolder2 and so on.
It should do nothing with the .yml files in the directories.

I think it can be accomplished with something like

```
#!/bin/env bash

folder=“folder/*/*”

for f in $folder do
if [ $f = *.txt ] then xargs mkdir -p
else echo “no txt files in folder..”
fi 
done
```

I think there could be a $(dirname $f) involved for echoing “no txt files in subfolder..”

I know I’m probably making a lot of mistakes but that’s why I came here, maybe some of you would like to help.

The reason for this script is I want to automate docker stack deploy for my docker swarm but unlike a regular docker-compose up swarm doesn’t create folders if they don’t exist.

Please just ask if I need to explain more about what it should and shouldn’t do.

EDIT:

I came up with some scripts but now I’m trying to combine the two,

```
cokehotdog@testvm:~$ for file in $files; do [[ $file == *.txt ]] && echo "$(basename $file) in $(basename $(dirname $file)) is a txt file" || echo "$(basename $file) in $(basename $(dirname $file)) is not a txt file"; done
test.txt in app1 is a txt file
test1.yml in app1 is not a txt file
test2.txt in app2 is a txt file
test2.yml in app2 is not a txt file
```

This should be combined with this

```
cokehotdog@testvm:~$ for file in $files; do [[ $file == *.txt ]] && cat $file | xargs mkdir -p -- && while read -r line; do echo "$line created";done < $file ; done
/home/cokehotdog/appdata/app1 created
/home/cokehotdog/appdata/app2 created
```

But when I try something like this I get an error and I’m stuck now

```
cokehotdog@testvm:~$ for file in $files; do [[ $file == *.txt ]] && cat $file | xargs mkdir -p -- && while read -r line; do echo "$line created";done < $file || echo "$(basename $file) in $(basename $(dirname $file)) is not a txt file"; done
cat: 'test/*/*.txt': No such file or directory
mkdir: missing operand
Try 'mkdir --help' for more information.
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the content of `folders.txt`?

Comment: Hi Fravadona, for example `appdata/wikijs` and on new line `appdata/radarr/config`

Comment: On Linux, the easiest way would be to use `cd ~; find . -name folders.txt -exec cat {} + | xargs -d '\n' mkdir -p` but you won't get the messages _“no txt file in subfolder1”_

Comment: `swarm doesn’t create folders if they don’t exist` this is something odd - why would you need to create _local_ folders in docker swarm? You should use docker volumes, you do not know on which host the service will be running on.

Comment: The folders are to be created in a nfs mount in my home directory

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
find folder -type f -name 'folders.txt' |
while IFS= read -r l; do
  (
     cd "$(dirname "$l")"
     xargs -d '\n' -t echo mkdir -p < "$l"
  )
done
```